# Recommended data-structure (for not querying nested data in node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

Mongo-DB doesn't support query with wildcards in a nested structure.

In a data-structure that looks like this:

```
Courses = [{
    'name': 'Learning node.js in 1 day',
    'roles': {
        'team':        { subscribed: [ 'User1' ] },
        'participant': { subscribed: [ 'User1', 'User2' ] },
        'host':        { optional: true, subscribed: [] }
    }
}]
```

We would need wildcard-lookup to find subscribers in different roles in order not to use a query like this:

```
{ $or : [ 
    {"roles.team.subscribed": 'User1'}, 
    {"roles.participant.subscribed": 'User1'}
    {"roles.host.subscribed": 'User1'} 
]}
```

Anyway this does not work if we have an open list of roles.

And if we change it to something like this:

```
'roles':  ['team', 'participant', 'host'],
'subscribed': [ 
    {'user':'User1', 'roles': ['team', 'participant']}, 
    {'user':'User2', 'roles': ['participant']} 
]
```

it gets similarly difficult to then find all participants of a course. Either way we have a problem to find all courses a user is subscribed to.

We think about creating a separate collection for subscriptions (back to relational):

```
{user_id: 'User1', course_id: '456', role: 'participant'}
{user_id: 'User1', course_id: '456', role: 'team'}
{user_id: 'User2', course_id: '456', role: 'participant'}
```

What is best practice?
We would like to be able to make all different sorts of queries and it seems difficult if it's buried in a nested structure...
Think this is quiet a fundamental question for data-stuctures in mongoDB.

Comment: I do think your structure is suitable to work with the aggregation framework. But it has a mistake (well, something that difficult your queries and the concept of Mongo is to create your structures based on your application needs). Roles should have been an array of roles [ { "team" : { ... }, "participant" : { ... } }. It would be way easier to query this structure. Let me think about the solution with your current structure.

Comment: Also Mongo has some nice courses about Transforming from Relational to non-SQL but in your case it's not a good idea to do it due to you don't have a previous Sql structure, so "back to relational" is not a good idea.

Comment: When you find yourself having this problem, I'd suggest you consider switching to a model where the role name is a field: `{ name: 'team', subscribed: [ 'User1' ], optional: true }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change your structure I think I would do something like this using aggregation framework. In case your fields inside roles are not so many and not completely manageable by users, in that case I would suggest you to use an array in roles and unwind it.
Let's take your first structure:

```
Courses = [{
    'name': 'Learning node.js in 1 day',
    'roles': {
        'team':        { subscribed: [ 'User1' ] },
        'participant': { subscribed: [ 'User1', 'User2' ] },
        'host':        { optional: true, subscribed: [] }
    }
}]
```

Project fields in this way:

name, roles.team, roles.participant, roles.host

So you will end up with this structure

```
Courses = [{
    'name': 'Learning node.js in 1 day',
    'roles.team.subscribed': [ 'User1' ] ,
    'roles.participant.subscribed': [ 'User1', 'User2' ] ,
    'roles.host.subscribed': subscribed: [] 
    }
}]
```

Then you can unwind subscribed field and get a cartesian product by subscribed, you need to unwind 3 times:

```
Courses = [
{
    'name': 'Learning node.js in 1 day',
    'roles.team.subscribed.values': 'User1' ,
    'roles.participant.subscribed.values': 'User1',
    'roles.host.subscribed.values': '' 
    }
},
{
    'name': 'Learning node.js in 1 day',
    'roles.team.subscribed.values': 'User1' ,
    'roles.participant.subscribed.values': 'User2',
    'roles.host.subscribed.values': '' 
    }
}
```

]

At the end you can match every role separately.

Of course you need to use aggregation framework, takes time to get use to it.

Comment: It's hard to make them work properly sometimes, if you come from Sql world (any kind of Sql database) you don't normally think on how to aggregate information because Sql resolves it using its own logic. You only need to keep in mind each step of aggregation reduces enough your data and creates a subset better for your goals.